# SQL Join date range to date: returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got a table (A) like this

```
ID_1 | ID_2 | Date
  A  |   B  | 2014-12-31
  A  |   B  | 2015-12-31
  A  |   B  | 2016-12-31
  A  |   B  | 2017-12-31
```

And I'm trying to join it with this table (B), so I get 1 corresponding value from table B for the date in table A. This could potentially be the max date if there are overlapping dateranges.

```
ID_1 | ID_2 | From_date  | To_date    | Value
  A  |   B  | 2014-05-01 | 2015-04-30 | 15 500
  A  |   B  | 2015-05-01 | 2016-02-29 | 17 000
  A  |   B  | 2016-10-03 | 2016-12-31 | 18 500
  A  |   B  | 2016-11-01 | 2016-12-31 | 35 000
  A  |   B  | 2017-09-01 | 2017-08-31 | 37 000
  A  |   B  | 2017-09-01 | NULL       | 37 500
```

I want to get this:

```
Date        | ID_1 | ID_2 | From_date  | To_date    | Value
2014-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2014-05-01 | 2015-04-30 | 15 500
2015-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2015-05-01 | 2016-02-29 | 17 000
2016-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2016-11-01 | 2016-12-31 | 35 000
2017-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2017-09-01 | NULL       | 37 500
```

I'm using the following code:

```
select
a.Date,
a.ID_1,
a.ID_2,
b.From_date,
b.To_date,
b.Value,
from table_A a
left join table_B b on b.ID_1 = a.ID_1 and b.ID_2=a.ID_2 and a.Date>=b.From_dat and (b.To_date is null or a.Dato<=b.To_date)
```

Currently this is what I get..

```
Date        | ID_1 | ID_2 | From_date  | To_date    | Value
2014-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2014-05-01 | 2015-04-30 | 15 500
2015-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2015-05-01 | 2016-02-29 | 17 000
2016-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2016-10-03 | 2016-12-31 | 18 500
2016-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2016-11-01 | 2016-12-31 | 35 000
2017-12-31  |   A  |  B   | 2017-09-01 | NULL       | 37 500
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Tag properly.  Which dbms?????????  Functions, especially date functions are very different from one product to another.  It's useless if someone post answer to the wrong dbms.

Comment: SQL server,sorry about that!

Answer (score -1):

```
just create the query,it works perfectly, it also helpful for long data in table 1 and table 2 please check---
---------------------
;with cte
as (
select a.Date,a.ID_1,a.ID_2,b.From_date,b.To_date,b.Value
from table1 a
left join
table2 b on b.ID_1 = a.ID_1 and b.ID_2=a.ID_2 and a.Date>=b.From_date and (b.To_date is null or a.Date<=b.To_date))
select  row_number()over (partition by date order by from_date desc )row ,ID_1,ID_2,From_date,To_date,Value into ##temp from cte
select *from ##temp
where row =1

----------------------
pls comment your result
---------
```